# Is MSVC 2010 a C++11-standard-compliant compiler

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, googletest

I was about to use [google test](https://github.com/google/googletest) for unit testing our `MSVC 2010` based project, but the `README.md` file of the **gtest v1.10.x** branch (the current latest) mentions *a C++11-standard-compliant compiler* in the *Build Requirements* section.

So is `MSVC 2010` a C++11-standard-compliant compiler, or should I rather use **gtest v1.7.0** which mentions *Microsoft Visual C++ 7.1 or newer* in the *Windows Requirements* section?

Comment: Visual studio 2019 isn't fully c++11 compliant https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=vs-2019

Comment: [@SidS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9125195/sid-s) I was told to just add unit testing, but thanks to [@Alan Birtles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5494370/alan-birtles)'s comment I will for now use `googletest v1.8.1` and later request the project to be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Around 2017, we had been facing too many random crashes with apps built using MSVC10 &  MSVC11 compilers. Upon analyzing this, we identified that the standard C++ library calls were the cause for the crashes though we did nothing wrong, and the code was perfectly written.

After some struggle debugging and study, we identified that **Microsoft's C++11 implementation was non standard and buggy, and caused unnecessary crashes**. For us, even the basic wait_for call on condition_variable had random crashes. [Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5b5009cc-c199-4e4c-bb24-69d4f36ae159/c11-concurrency-bug-since-update-3-?forum=winappswithnativecode) is one such MSDN reference for you.

We contacted Microsoft regarding this, and their reply was,

> "I'm sorry, but no hotfixes for this bug are available. I strongly
>   recommend upgrading to the latest released version of VS (currently VS
>   2017 15.4), as we have fixed many bugs in the STL's multithreading
>   machinery over the years."

We had to move all our projects to VS2017 (The latest one at that time) to get rid of the crashes. I wouldn't recommend you using those buggy compilers either.

Better stick to older compilers(VC8/VC9) or move to the latest one (VS2019). We had no issues after migrating to VS2017.

Answer (score 1):

No, MSVC 2010 is not fully C++11 compliant. However, it does provide many C++11 features. You could try and compile the latest google_test with it, or just use an older version.